# jQuery UI datepicker & dialog sends data to # when a date is selected

Tags: jquery-ui

jQuery **UI datepicker y dialog**

When a date is selcted in a datepicker that is in a dialog, the data is sent to #.  When a date is selected, only the text should be selected and the data should not be sent until the submit is clicked.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: ähem... I do understand a bit spanish but I think this is an english site and not an international... additionally its a question I think belongs more to SO.com

Comment: @Disk: Feel free to translate if you can. ;)

Comment: @Josh: I´m not yet allowed to edit.. and I don`t understand enough to translate properly ^^ but I still think it is a question for stackoverflow because jQuery is a Javascript lib.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. It may be by the same reason and the solution can help you:

- [jquery ui datepicker IE reload or jumps to the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193169/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-reload-or-jumps-to-the-top-of-the-page)